# Use specific language for comment section

Tags: comments, plugin-wpml, language

On some pages I have the possibility to write a comment (name, email, website, comment). The labels are now in my default language. Now I want to use the English labels for the whole comment section. How can I reach this?

I searched a little bit and found out that I can set some labels with

```
<?php comment_form(array('label_submit' => 'Submit comment' )); ?>
```

But then I would have to set each label and I don't know if I can find and catch all these labels. Are there other ways doing this?

PS: The comments.php is from Twenty Eleven Theme and I'm using WPML.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of `comments.php` I use the following code:

```
<?php comment_form(array('comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>', 'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked *</p>', 'comment_notes_after' => '', 'title_reply' => 'Leave a Reply', 'title_reply_to' => 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'label_submit' => 'Post comment', 'cancel_reply_link' => 'Cancel reply' )); ?>
```

It's not perfect but the best I have.